# Matrix inversion problem in ridge regression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning, inverse, orthogonal-matrices

The ridge estimator can be written in the following way, where the singular value decomposition of X is $X=UDV^{'}$.

[image]

I can't quite figure out how the last step (4th step) was obtained from the 3rd one. I think it is something about matrix inverse. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: $(ABC)^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Comment: HI, i know that rule. But can i use that when there is a sum of matrices as well ?

Comment: There is no sum, $B=D^2+\lambda I $

Comment: $A=V $ and $C=V^T$

Comment: I see. Then i have to use the orthogonal property of matrix V to obtain the desired result. isn't it  ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Hi  To find the inverse like this, A B and C should be square matrices isn't it ?   So is there any way to simplify $(ABC)^{-1}$ ,if A and C are not square matrices ?

Comment: What does the SVD theorem tell you about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $V$ (and $U$) is a unitary matrix, i.e., $VV^T = I \Leftrightarrow V^{-T} = V$,   and $V^TV = I \Leftrightarrow V^T = V^{-1}$,
\begin{align}
\beta(\lambda) 
&=\left(VD^2V^T + \lambda V V^T\right)^{-1} VDU^TY \\
&= \left(V\left(D^2 + \lambda I \right)V^T\right)^{-1} VDU^TY \\
&= V^{-T}\left(D^2 + \lambda I \right)^{-1} V^{-1} VDU^TY \\
&= V\left(D^2 + \lambda I \right)^{-1} V^T VDU^TY \\
\end{align}